# Problema com 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, api, apache-cordova, instagram-api

Segue o código

```
  angular.module('App', [])
    .controller('InstaController',function($scope, $http){
        $scope.busca;
        $scope.buscar = function(){
            $scope.getInsta($scope.busca);
        }


        $scope.getInsta = function(tag){
            var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=6f6a0f971acf482a8dc4f9e66c2ec8b9';
            if(tag !== undefined){
                url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+tag+"/media/recent?client_id=6f6a0f971acf482a8dc4f9e66c2ec8b9"
            }
            $http.get(url)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.inst = data.data;
                console.log($scope.inst);

            });
        }
        $scope.getInsta();
    });
```

Segue o erro
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=6f6a0f971acf482a8dc4f9e66c2ec8b9. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Obs: Estou Usando Compilando na Build o .Apk Funciona normal mas no Navegador.

link do App na Web allandasilva.com.br/App/

"resolvi" com um plugin do Chrome

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Como Resolver sem usar a externação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não tem "allow" no response header da api.instagram.
O único jeito é utilizando GET + JSONP. Da uma olhada em http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ na sessão JSONP.

É necessário um CALLBACK no endpoint para JSONP. (&callback=callbackFunction)

Exemplo:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/coffee/media/recent?access_token=fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d&callback=callbackFunction
```

Callback function:

```
callbackFunction({
    ...
});
```

Comment: Valeu Vou dar uma olhada